# Using confusing variable names in questions

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Take a look at this post:
[java 8 stream groupingBy sum of composite variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888545/java-8-stream-groupingby-sum-of-composite-variable)

While this is a good question, the use of "Something" "Anything" and "Nothing" as names is problematic.

Those words have meaning when describing a problem, particularly with collections processing, and overloading them instead of more standard X/Y/Z, first/second/third, myClass/myVariable1/myFunction, foo/bar, etc causes unnecessary confusion.

Should I edit the question to clean up the variables?
Should we as a community start soft-enforcing coding standards for questions to prevent this?

Comment: I always start my C programs with 'int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;'  and if I need an integer variable, I just pick a letter.  It works great for avoiding all those 'Undeclared varaible' syntax errors!

Comment: I'm really not worried about general coding practices here. I'm more concerned with the "clear" part of the "clear and concise" guideline. It's a question dealing with the processing of collections. Using any name that is also terms used for describing the state of collections is just downright problematic. "I have a list of something that contains a list of anything which is made up of nothing" is LITERALLY the way to read one of the structures in the question. Am i really the only one who had to read it 3 times to get it straight in my head?

Comment: Sidebar, I get downvoted like crazy when asking what I dont think are unreasonable questions. What can i do better?

Comment: I would guess that many people disagree about your assertion that `Something` is bad name for class/variable. It is not much different than regular `Cat` and `Animals`... Note that essentially you have "feature request" to start editing posts to align with your preferred coding style (even if you tagged as "discussion"), so post is getting votes for disagreement with your proposal too.

Comment: While I disagree with your take on this issue, this, as a [discussion], is a fine question.

Comment: I frequently change names when dealing with stuff I don't want to give away, but keep the answers around for everyone for the generic solution. And while your linked question is still clear enough, I believe you'd be downvoted far less if you linked to one that misused singular/plural or decided "param" was a descriptive name for a variable. (Much like code I frequently have to fix). Your downvotes just mean that not everyone here has taken over nightmares from other people as much. They'll change their tune after they see some nightmares themselves... they always do... mwahahaha.

Comment: There is a bigger problem really: most of the development world stinks at naming elements in code. The terseness of lambda's in Java makes that all the more visible. The best thing to do is to just get good at deciphering a mess, it's what we all have to do. Trying to fix all the poor naming in all the code is the act of ice skating uphill.

Comment: To be clear, I'm absolutely not suggesting the question should have been closed. It is the only question I've found on stack that address my problem: needing to do a multivariate aggregation of a large data set. The problem here is that in English, especially when talking about collections, the phrase "a collection of nothing" when interpreted in you head is easy to be translated as "an empty collection". The purpose of this sits is to take real problems and answer them in a way that future people can easily solve a similar problem. Using non standard naming conventions doesn't help that goal

Comment: Using non standard naming conventions that, when read aloud, become dependent on the formatting of the words is particularly not helpful. What I would like to do is propose an edit (because you can't just blind edit) which substitute less context sensitive names, and fixes some plurality problems, but otherwise doesn't change anything about the content of the question or the answers.

Answer (score 16):

Some points of emphasis to make:

- **Those are *class* names, not *variable* names.**  The OP elected to name their classes those names, which is...fine.  Whatever.  Not the major detail here.
- **Java doesn't care *what* your identifiers are named, so long as they're legal.**  All of the identifiers would pass muster and be compilable, which is what we're looking for in this scenario.
- **You cannot enforce coding standards on anyone here.**  There are people who believe the curly brace should go on a new line, and there are people where it's okay to omit the curly braces at all in certain `if` blocks.  Edits to improve the coding style ***destroy*** the original context of the question, *especially* if the bug happens to be edited out by an outgoing editor who believes that they're doing The Right Thing™ by editing this code.
- **Did you know that OPs often post questions with variables in their native language?**  Again, Java doesn't care as long as you're consistent.  You shouldn't either.

Don't mess with it.  The code is fine.  The question is fine.  Take more time to understand and read through it.  This is a scenario in which editing is a ***bad*** idea.

Comment: 'You cannot enforce coding standards on anyone here' true, but you can close-vote questions with pagefulls of sigle-letter var names as 'Unclear' and move on to the next question istead of wasting time on messes.

Comment: That's closer to what has me asking this. trying to understand a question with "Collections of Something which contain collections of Anything made of Nothing" is not what i would consider "clear". But the content is good for a question, i just think the names need to be cleaned up to remove the distraction from the meat-and-potatoes

Comment: @Stephan:  Poor variable names (like i, j, k, argVar, etc) make for an "unclear" question.  This is not unclear.  You're welcome to vote that way but I don't believe there'd be many who would agree with you on that aspect.

Comment: I agree that those would also be unclear names, I personally try to use someClass, anotherClass, myClass, anObject, someOtherObject etc. That's along the lines of what i would edit to, if i were to edit the question, but seems the bottom line is "Stephan no touchie" lol

Comment: "Again, Java doesn't care as long as you're consistent. You shouldn't either." But if the rest of the question is in English, which we've agreed to as a site, it makes the question much more readable *for everyone coming later on* if the code is in English too. Likewise if you follow naming conventions, it's less distracting - so it makes for a better question. I *do* care about the readability of questions, so I *do* care about people not following naming conventions. I know the compiler doesn't care, but the compiler isn't a person - readers *are* people.

Comment: I don't think the cited question is too bad, but your answer appears to basically be saying "If the compiler can handle it, there's nothing wrong with the question." I disagree with that. The compiler wouldn't care if you named all your identifiers `__`, `___`, `____` etc - but I'd have real issues with a question that did that.

Comment: @DaisyShipton: A question written in English with Dutch identifiers is *perfectly* on topic, especially given that not only can we *not* control what someone is going to call their identifiers or variables, but again, so long as Java's capable of lexing it and compiling it, all it takes is for us to plop it into our favorite IDE and run it to see what's going on.  That's what my argument ultimately boils down to here.  The OP isn't going out of their way to obfuscate or confuse the reader.

Comment: I feel like the argument being made is a red herring, since any code with *terrible* identifiers should be closed with "unclear", but if there's a **genuine attempt at clarity** and there is **no intentional obfuscation or ambiguity** in the code, then they've done their part in supplying us with an MCVE.

Comment: @Makoto: It's on-topic, but I think it would provide more value with English identifiers. The OP in that case may not be going out of their way to obfuscate or confuse, but personally I think if you're going to ask people to help, I think it makes sense to go out of your way to be as clear as possible and provide the most long-term value for the site.

Comment: @Makoto: If you think it's a red herring, maybe you should change the bar from "The Java compiler can cope with it" which is the thrust of your second and fourth bullet points.

Comment: So I'll just be blunt then @DaisyShipton:  if the code is understandable and is not intentionally obfuscated, it's probably fine.  If you find the code to be unclear, but do not believe it to be maliciously or terribly obfuscated, the right action is to **disengage with the question**.  Reading code is part of our jobs, and we can get less than desirable identifiers.  Instead of nitpicking over less-than-desirable identifiers, we should be focusing on whether or not it can be *understood*.  That's all there is to it.  If you can't understand it, disengage with the question.

Comment: So I should stop editing code which has been horribly formatted in terms of indentation (not moving curly braces, just making indentation better)? That massively improves readability IMO (often avoiding scrolling) with no loss of information. I don't think disengaging is the right approach. Nagging isn't either, but a gentle request to follow naming conventions seems reasonable to me, for the sake of future readers. Whether or not a question can be understood isn't a binary property; I think it's reasonable to considerately ask users to follow naming conventions for example.

Comment: (Requesting different bracing is a different matter, given how widely varying that is. But in a language like Java or C# where the naming conventions are *so* widely followed, I think it's entirely reasonable.)

Comment: I really feel like you're nitpicking now @DaisyShipton.  Indentation isn't a variable identifier, and it's not desirable to format to indentation at *all* in Python due to the fact that indentation is a part of the actual code.  Asking users to follow conventions with their code feels like a hollow exercise that we use to justify *not* answering questions as often because it doesn't "match convention".  It's one thing if they are using horrendous and unclear identifiers.  It's *quite* another if you simply don't ***agree*** with the style of their identifiers.

Comment: My point is that around indentation is that just because code is "understandable" doesn't mean it can't be significantly improved. (Completely agree about Python for indentation, btw.) I wouldn't use conventions as a justification not to answer a question - I would typically mention it as an aside while starting to answer the question. Fundamentally for me it comes down to what the purpose of the site is: to answer that one user's question, or to provide a long-term benefit for all the thousands of future readers with the same problem. The more we can do for them, the better.

Comment: But it sounds like we'll probably have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @DaisyShipton:  I've largely surmised that we're agreeing on many points, but I feel like you're splitting hairs.  I'll let it lie for now, though.

Answer (score 7):

Seeing your question and the other answer I feel like an important feature is being ignored:

> The comment

Instead of editing the post or flagging it you could simply comment asking the OP to change their variable names. It's even stated in the comment box itself:

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements.

Comment: Indeed - I wouldn't start renaming identifiers in a question's code (unless the OP has requested that) but I think it *is* reasonable to suggest ways in which the readability of the question could be improved. That should be done with empathy and kindness though, not rudely.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but it'd be cool if this answer used `their` instead of `his` :)

Comment: @Max I would say your comment is perfectly on topic given my answer is about using comments to suggest improvements. And your comment can be seen as an example of this.

Answer (score -2):

In addition to the other good answers, it is worth noting that the problem you identify can be averted by using inline code formatting to distinguish `Anything`, an identifier found in a piece of code, from "Anything", the familiar English word. I have just edited the question to that effect.

(By the way, this kind of disambiguation is sometimes crucial. Over at [haskell], for instance, it makes perfect sense to say "`ByteString` is a functor which is not a `Functor`". Marking the difference without resorting to formatting would require a rather long-winded periphrasis.)