# Am I rude and abusive suggesting English variable names?

Tags: support

I was answering [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841957/add-items-in-nested-dictionary/61842097?noredirect=1#comment109382638_61842097) which used variable names in a foreign language, maybe Dutch.

In my answer I suggested to use English variable names, because I found it rather difficult to figure out what OP wanted to achieve. If they were Chinese, Russion or Greek characters, I could probably not have helped at all.

Now, a user pointed out in a comment that this is considered rude and abusive.

[image: Comment section for reference]

If that's really the case, I'd like to change my way of writing - or maybe remove myself from this site, because it will be more and more difficult to contribute on this site, if everyone writes in his native tongue.

Which guideline am I violating?

Edit: Since [@ChrisF♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) removed the affected sentence, it seems that I should really not suggest English in code.

Comment: I would flag that comment as *rude* and move on ...

Comment: Just as a note - I edited out that last sentence to prevent your answer getting (more) rude/abusive flags. I'm not going to comment further at this stage.

Comment: IMHO it's a valid suggestion, and you've included it in the correct place (right at the end of your answer, and merely as a helpful suggestion). Calling it bigoted is more rude than making the suggestion itself.

Comment: It's not rude or abusive to suggest that, when asking for help on an English-only site, part of creating a MRE should be translating identifiers to English to help readers understand the logic they're supposed to be helping with. Is [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments) rude and abusive for suggesting that comments should be in English when sharing code?

Comment: Also while we're here, can someone explain what "Please remove yourself" means besides coming across as someone saying "GTFO" while trying to be polite and failing miserably?

Comment: I'm not following Meta closely for some years. A lot of things have changed. I still find SO useful and I will adapt to change when needed. Thus I'm glad when people point me to wrong behavior (at least better than just flagging for deletion without me getting to ever know this).

Comment: I just need to point out that while suggesting it on its own isn't rude, it really depends on how it's presented. Similarly to telling people to google stuff, it's all about doing it properly and in a way that isn't rude. You didn't say anything crossing a line here, in my opinion. The comment from TheLazyScripter, however, does cross a line. And suggesting english variable/function names when asking on Stack is actually something I can get behind. It's a lot easier to help when you're able to understand what the various names mean, and it's more likely for OP to get help.

Comment: Also, while we're on the topic of language, all questions on SO (stackoverflow.com and meta.stackoverflow.com; NOT the other language variants like ru.stackoverflow.com) are in English. Entirely non-english posts can be closed as "unclear" (... or whatever is the consensus with these new close reasons. I'm out of the loop on that, ngl). Variable, function, and other construct names are a bit of an exception to that.

Comment: @Nick: Maybe it just means "Please remove *that text that I am referring to*, yourself".  I hope he didn't mean "kill yourself". My primary language is not English. These things are really difficult for me. For me, the interpretation spectrum is large.

Comment: I don't think this belongs in an answer to be honest. Unless it really is part of the answer. Apart from that I'd refrain from suggesting such though, even in comments. It's just variable names for what I imagine is a small program or a snippet.

Comment: @Scratte Did you look at the question, I have *no* idea what each variable is meant to be, and I'm not going to make effort to figure it out when OP won't make effort to provide meaningful variable names in the appropriate language... I wouldn't DV, but I wouldn't make an effort

Comment: @Nick Yes :) It's not new. I've come across it before on Stack Overflow. Sometimes I will even paste them in translate.google.com. But it so happens, that I understand half of those :D

Comment: If you want to be on the safe side you could rephrase to something like *I hope I got the variable names correctly interpreted and assume the right functional meaning for them when I translated those to English.* That sentence is free of opinion, leaves the blame for getting it wrong at your end and has more then enough hints for a reasonable OP to understand that they made the task harder for you. Most Dutch folks will "get" the message and their next MCVE will probably have english variable names.

Comment: @rene: thanks for being around. That sounds like a good suggestion.

Comment: It's also fine to use comments for clarification. "Does variable [blah] mean height?" or even "I don't know Dutch and it's unclear what your variables are for, can you explain?" would work. But I agree with Scratte that suggestions for how to write the question don't belong in answer posts.

Comment: Side note: @ThomasWeller you probably should have flagged the comment as "rude" and not reply to it.

Comment: Considering that English has essentially become a global language, and in particular is this site's primary language, I'd personally consider this a valid suggestion.  While English names aren't a necessity, they make the question easier to parse for the community at large (as a melting pot of people of all languages, we _do_ need to have at least one common tongue to communicate), which in turn increases the chances of it getting a useful answer.  I think it's telling that ChrisF's stated reason for removing your suggestion wasn't that it violated any rules, but to protect _you_ from abuse.

Comment: @ChrisF Just a heads up, *"practicing"* is the AmE spelling of *"practising"*, as right as we think we are, we shouldn't be enforcing our BrE standards on others :p

Comment: @nick oops. That was my spell checker highlighting the word and me not paying full attention.

Comment: So, I'm Dutch and, as most Dutchies, I've learned to speak English since Kindergarten. I do, however, have huge problems with Arabic and Asian scribbles. I cannot make heads or tails of something written in those languages.  SO is about helping people and trying to figure out what they mean and not about venting opinions. When I don't understand a question I either ask for a clarification or simply ignore it and move on. I appreciate the effort ppl trying to make in writing in English while it's not their native language. We can't all be perfect linguists, no need to get offensive over that...

Comment: In any case, meta information does not belong in posts (questions or answers). That is what comments are for (even if they are called "comments"). For instance, you could have asked in comments to the question if the variable names could be translated.

Comment: @Nick , AT jonrsharpe : It doesn't belong in an answer. It is meta information (something *about* the question, not the question itself) that should be in comments.

Comment: @Zoe: The same could be said for one-letter variable names (except the Fortran-inherited `i`, `j`, and `k`). They don't make much sense without extra context. I am looking at you, *[Numerical recipes in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_Recipes#Titles_in_the_series_(partial_list))*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Except `c` is normally a character, `n` is normally a max number, `x`, `y`, and `z` are coordinates, `w` is normally the homogeneous vert. comp., `u` and `v` are texture coordinates, all of which are fairly standard and well understood. And re: it not belonging in an answer, I wholeheartedly disagree, it's a valid suggestion for improving the code, especially when sharing. It's not about their post, it's about their *code*

Comment: Although I'm no longer active on SO (for exactly that reason) : There is a strong tendency to consider someone as "rude and abusive" whenever someone says that this person is "rude and abusive", because ... feelings ... and feelings don't lie. I'm watching the boat sink, and read https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Zauberlehrling when I'm bored.

Comment: Especially seeing as they **supposed** to be writing new code that provides a MCVE specifically for SO, rather than just copy/pasting what they have,  doing that in English if they are able would seem to make sense.

Comment: Kudo's on you for ___correctly___ guessing that those variables are in Dutch, instead of calling it German :D

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No.  You are not rude or abusive.

Different people speaking different languages is a problem.  This is a fact of life.  In order to answer questions, we must be able to understand them.  Different languages get in the way.

If someone writes code that is difficult to understand **because** the variable names (or comments) are not in English then this is a problem:

- for us, because we can't give meaningful answers
- for the OP, because the OP won't get meaningful answers
- for future readers.

It *can be* particularly problematic when the code doesn't actually make sense and you need to understand what the OP is *trying* to do.  This is often the case for "beginner" problems where the OP's code is nonsensical and their descriptions are incoherent.  (Not in >>this<< example though, IMO!)

One approach is to suggest (politely!) that they translate their variable names, etc.  However, the consensus is that such a suggestion does not belong in an Answer.  I would be inclined to comment on the Question something like this:

> "I am afraid that I don't understand what this code is trying to do.   It *may* help us to understand your problem if you translated the variable names and comments into English."

Another approach is to (politely!) qualify your Answer; e.g.

> "I am not sure I fully understand your code, but ..."

and then proceed to answer based on what you understood *despite* the variable names.

Another approach is to just vote-to-close as "unclear what you are asking" and move on.  This assumes that variable translation is *really* necessary.  As @Scratte comments, non-English variable names are not a *prima facie* reason to close a question.  The vote-to-close privilege should be exercised *responsibly*.

The final approach is to just ignore the Question entirely.

---

Note that this is **not a code style issue**<sup>1</sup>.  It is a communication issue.  We are not suggesting that the OP change how they write code for their own purposes.  We are only concerned about the code that they ask for our help on.

- We need to understand the code to answer the Question.
- Future readers often need to understand the code so that they can figure out if the Question matches *their* problem.

Which leads me to a final point.  I think that we should **only** be suggesting that the OP translates variable names and comments **if it is necessary** to make the Question understandable to you.  If you can work it out *or if you could work it out if you put in a bit of effort* don't suggest.

I don't speak Dutch, but I think I can work out what nearly all of the variable names mean from the code and the context.  So *in this case*, I would not see the need to comment.  But I only speak for myself.

---

<sup>1 - And commenting on style is not necessarily off-topic anyway.  It depends on the programming language and whether it has strong / widely accepted style conventions.</sup>

Comment: I can't find it at the moment, but I'm pretty sure there's a post here on meta mentioning that variable names not in English is not a reason to close. But you have a point when the code is too difficult to understand. There are some hints that even confusing names are OK though: [Using confusing variable names in questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365939)

Comment: @Scratte - I agree.  Variable names not in English is not a reason to close.  But a Question being incomprehensible when **among other things** the variables are not in English is a good reason.

Comment: But it doesn't belong in an answer. Meta information (*about* a post) belongs in comments (to the question in this particular case).

Comment: This was a **bad take**.  If the compiler is happy with non-English variable names, then you should be okay with it too.  To suggest that they also code in English when their first language isn't English (but the question is *otherwise* written in English) is pretty bad.

Comment: @Makoto - My answer is a lot more nuanced than that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Suggesting is okay.
2. Not using English variable names worsens the quality of the questions.
3. It is also a clear signature that the comprehensibility of the question is not so important for the OP.

Actually, (3) is what makes my opinion about this phenomenon more negative as it is reasonable. We are not a free problem solving machine. I see many times, particularly in first posters, that they communicate as if they would talk with some AI.

Maybe a standard comment like this would help a lot: *"Hey, we are not a bot, we are real humans. You are asking us to solve your problem for free. Please honor us by doing all what you can, to make our task easier".*

I think you are pretty right.

---

<sub>Side remark: The whole problem would be non-existent if the SO could exist on any language where there are enough users for a healthy site...</sub>

Comment: Re *"they communicate as if they would talk with some AI."*: Do you have some examples?

Comment: @PeterMortensen [My pleasure](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a1d..%20closed%3ayes%20score%3a..-5), particularly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65156475/1783163). This is an example if the OP does not understand that he should do all what he can to make the answer, created by living humans, most likely. Example for non-English variable names would require more digging.

Answer (score -8):

Short answer: They probably need to switch to their language's version of Stack Overflow.

There are already some versions of Stack Overflow of a certain language. The biggest one (apart from English) is the [Russian version](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), though I'm not sure if there is a Dutch version however (figuring out the name of variables are all Dutch).

Although this means that you're not rude or abusive, I believe they still have to go to their language's version. Maybe even moderators can migrate these questions to those sites.

**UPDATE:** From @10Rep's perspective, migration isn't actually required. I still do believe that they have to go to their language's Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why? Just ask them to define the variables in a comment. No migration required.

Comment: @10Rep I sometimes think in different ways on my perspective of this site. Migrating **could** be a solution, but I guess that also helps.

Comment: Migration is difficult. It can also fail, which results in the question getting destroyed in some cases.

Comment: @10Rep You remind me of my 1st question on the meta. I will still leave the edit out, only because the answer seems reasonable enough.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. Just wanted to put my point across. I think migration is not really required. Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402216/are-error-messages-required-to-be-posted-in-english.

Comment: I just want to note that moderators on Stack Overflow are *extremely* reluctant to migrate questions to language-localized versions of Stack Overflow. Since only high-quality questions should be migrated (to avoid dumping our unwanted garbage on other sites), we would need to be able to read the foreign-language post and understand it, and there's a very small chance that the typical SO mod would be able to do. Therefore, it's not recommended that you flag (or expect) non-English posts for migration. Just flag them as off-topic. (Variable names can just be edited to English, of course.)

Comment: There's also no Stack Overflow in Dutch... I mean, you can believe all you want that's what they should do, but if there's no Stack Overflow in their language, they just can't do it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey And this is bad. Wikipedia exists on languages with lesser than a million native speakers, and it is no problem for them.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica So should we request a Dutch Stack Overflow?

Comment: @HenryWillies Non-English SO proposals are officially forbidden. The company fears to lose control and anyways totally incompetent. This was the first case as it became pretty clear to me, there is no other explanation for that than total incompetence.

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe if the remote site could decide if they want to import the closed posts from anywhere...

Comment: We are somewhat reluctant to "silo" off the knowledge contained in Stack Overflow, which would be the effect of creating a localized version of the site for each language. I see no advantage in creating a Dutch version of the site. The English version works just fine, even if you have to use some sort of translation tool.

Answer (score -15):

> If they were Chinese, Russion or Greek characters, I could probably not have helped at all.

I don't think this is completely true. Variable names are just identifiers, they can be in any language or none at all and as such don't change how the code works. Of course, descriptive, short variable names are better than arbitrary or overly long names, helping to understand code. Since English is the most widely used language it makes sense to actually use meaningful English variable names (at least when asking on Stack Overflow).

You or the question creator or someone else could have improved the question and renamed variables, but this could in itself introduce additional errors and often it's not so easy to decide how a variable should be named best. Opinions on that probably differ.

In this concrete example:

```
klaar = False
while klaar != True:
    product = int(input("type a product code or press 0 to close: "))
    if product in kera:
        alijst[product] = kera[product]
    else:
        if product == 0:
            klaar = True
```

The name `klaar` looks as good to me as the translations to English (ready for what?), `alijst` is also only marginally less helpful than `alist` (which is a dictionary, not a list).

I would give the question asker a bit of slack regarding the naming of variables in code examples, but I can of course use meaningful English variable names in code examples in my answer. I could even after posting an answer polish the question and improve variable names there.

A possible renaming of variables in the question is to me more of a meta thing and should rather be a comment to the question than part of an answer (something like "I have difficulties understanding your code, please consider translating used variable's names to English to help me and others understand the problem better.").

Finally, the question really isn't a great one. The code is not minimal and the problem is not stated clearly (How exactly are prizes supposed to be added together? Where are the prizes stored?). If these weren't the case, the variable names might be less of a problem if at all.

Summary: Your comment in the answer was not rude or abusive but at the wrong place and in this case maybe not necessary. The comment calling you out, however, was rude and abusive. It's really good that it's gone.