# Are error messages required to be posted in English?

Tags: discussion, questions, error-message, english

Recently a conversation arose in a chatroom regarding an error message in a post:

> ```
> Skript:  C:\Users\<omitted>\AppData\Local\Temp\Signatur.vbs
> Zeile:   274
> Zeichen: 1
> Fehler:  Typenkonflikt: '[string: "+49 173 <omitted>"]'
> Code:    800A000D
> Quelle:  Laufzeitfehler in Microsoft VBScript
> ```

The error had been provided as an image (which was incorrect) and in non-English (which is canonically accepted for *code*).

A comment was left under the post with the following content<sub>(emphasis my own)</sub>:

> Please don't post errors as images and especially not when they are non-English. **All errors should be clear and provided in English.** ...

The argument given is that SO questions are supposed to be written in English. However there were arguments against it asking how errors are different to code and so should be allowed in non-English as long as the rest of the post was correctly in English.

*Despite* us all knowing the guidance of the canonical [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content) we were unable to reach a consensus in chat as it does not provide guidance on error messages.

Should error messages be translated into English prior to posting or is it acceptable for them to be left in non-English (like code)?

If a consensus can be reached by the community can we then update the guidance at [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content) to include this updated guidance?

Comment: I am very confused about this. My take is that error messages are code too.

Comment: @Scratte If it's an error message that you write yourself and tell the code when to throw it, then yes, that is code. If it is a system error message that you don't have any control over, that's not really code, it's just a system message.

Comment: I posted [an answer about this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176545/164403) on the Overmeta way back in 2013, and its main point still stands today: By providing error messages in your native language, you are restricting your audience to the users who can understand it. No more, no less.

Comment: @Nick My gut reaction is anything that is relevant for understanding/answering the question should be in English. And if something isn't relevant, it probably shouldn't be included. Not sure how that gut reaction holds up once it starts hitting specific cases, though.

Comment: @TylerH I do not agree. I do not think uses should translate system error messages. To me that is certainly code.

Comment: @Scratte you have just repeated your first comment.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Does that mean that error messages not in English should not be a close reason?

Comment: @Scratte not really. You can understand code without translating variables and comments, but in error messages, understanding the language is actually critical. Imagine if you were presented with a ヌルポインター例外 - would you automatically be able to understand it means "NullPointerException"? At least according to some shoddy Google Translate into a semi-random language, but the point still holds: you can't guess what an error message means in the same way you can read code. Errors depend on (human) language - code doesn't

Comment: @Scratte, not in my opinion, no, but I'm usually quite biased about closing a question for that kind of reason. Better try to translate the message if you feel like it, or ask the questioner to do it. I would advise against posting non-English code for the reasons explained above, but it's not the end of the world if you do.

Comment: Also, most search engines are able to apply similar words when doing the actual search, meaning even if the translation from whatever source language to english is slightly bad, it's actually possible to find other questions on the same error message. Searching through localized error messages in several languages does not provide that same opportunity

Comment: For the benefit of any doubt, I'm hoping to find some consensus, rather than just the thoughts of the active meta users, so this post will stay without an accepted answer to allow time for that to happen (and if any mods want to feature it so that as large a group of people can be reached that might help *hint hint* >.>)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I disagree; the entire post needs to be understandable. Writing your question in French doesn't only restrict your audience, it's off-topic and should be closed on SO. Error messages are often necessary to be understood, and restricting your audience hasn't much to do with it. It's either understandable to someone who speaks English (not necessarily native), or isn't. In the former case, it's OK, in the latter, it's not.

Comment: ... did somebody say "[error messages in French](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22780466/2821954)"...?

Comment: @Adriaan, I do agree with you that it helps a lot with one's question for it to be understandable. I only question the necessity to close questions containing a glimpse of non-English instead of, say, improving them. But I do not wish to enter a holy war about that here, it is not that important in the end.

Comment: Error messages **are not code** they can be output from code or by the underlying operating system. If you are trying to resolve someone's problem usually the error message is key to that understanding.

Comment: @Nick was going to post it myself *(as it was originally raised in chat over [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64442357/vbscript-error-type-mismatch-code-800a000d#comment113950705_64442357) I left on a question)*, but you beat me to it.

Comment: @TylerH absolutely agree. If it's intrinsic to understanding the question being asked it should be written in English.

Comment: @Lankymart Yeah, I pinged you in chat when I posted it in case you were interested. If you disagree with the current answers (as I have seen your comments on them) I do encourage you to post an answer so we can actually get the community opinion on it, otherwise it appears that errors will be exempt from from the english only rule.

Comment: @AndrewT. not surprised it was closed.

Comment: They should be translated, besides the original text, also tablenames functions names procedure names vaariables and so  on

Comment: @nbk start talking about variable names, table names etc, then it's gone too far.

Comment: @Lankymart variable anems give a hint ti what the variable is used for meinkleinesMärchenkind if that is my variablename explains everything that will be found there. The same goes for function and so on, if the logic of your prgram isn't clear , or the snippet quite short, the variablenames a vital to help, also for column nmaes

Comment: If the error message is in Portuguese, Russian, Spanish, Japanese we also could send such cases to the localized StackOverflows. That would be fitting in a way.

Comment: @Trilarion Not if only the error message is non-English, one of the examples I gave in chat is that I work on non-English systems that give non-English errors, but I exclusively code and speak English, a localized SO is worthless for that

Comment: @Nick My fault. I assumed you would speak both English and the localized language. Now it could happen that you work on a non-English system and get non-English errors but also are unable to translate the error message to English.

Comment: Debugging aside, the question will be of limited use to future visitors / searchers if a transaltion is not provided somewhere in the title or question body.

Comment: Google translate output: "Script: C: \ Users \ <omitted> \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Signatur.vbs
Row: 274
Characters: 1
Error: Type conflict: '[string: "+49 173 <omitted>"]'
Code: 800A000D
Source: runtime error in Microsoft VBScript" Maybe we should just require people to use a translate service if they do not speak the language.

Comment: Microsoft has a page for localized error lookup (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Emt). I tried it with this error message. Didn't work. It redirected me to an error page saying at least in English "We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found." after clicking on search.

Comment: Assuming a system error message, I'd say you need the English error message... before you even ask any question. Because the english error message likely produces more relevant search results. If you can't produce the english version of the system error, you likely did not do your due diligence.

Comment: @Gimby That's assuming working on a system that's _in your control_, for example client systems could be heavily locked down and that could not be a possibility

Comment: @Zoe What's the alternative? Should a user who's been using Japanese error messages just *know* that the English equivalent is called NullPointerException? You are proposing that people should post something different to what their computer outputted, which is very frowned upon for good reasons.

Comment: Maybe relevant in case the error message comes from C# [Exception messages in English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209133/exception-messages-in-english) or [Solution to the "Localized exceptions" problem](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/474). Maybe we should just collect a list of similar questions and then just tell people to try to get English error messages.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, but in that case, what use is it to others? I'd argue not very.

Comment: @Lankymart Same as the use of an English error message that you personally don't happen to understand.

Comment: @user253751 I don't think I've ever come across an error message I don't understand, usually, there is at least some hint as to what the issue is. Even if it's just Error 45 or something like that I'll know where to look. Probably google "Error 45" and some other context related to the framework or library I'm using.

Comment: @Peter I tried so hard to avoid your Active Reading edits and I missed a single capital letter, damn it xd

Comment: I immediately thought of PHP's `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` upon seeing this question

Comment: There are messaging apps and browsers, that have built in translator utilities for anyone that need them. SO could provide a link too. Would even help those non-English speaking folks who use SO and can't make any sense of certain English messages

Comment: to the people who say just use google translate or other translation apps: they can work, but these are error messages, which could include code, file paths and other sutff

Comment: @KetZoomer. Sure, I wasn't talking about automated translation. That puts too much burden on SO anyway. It's just a tool, for when needed.

Comment: Some statistics about how often that happens "Typkonflikt" (2x) "Typenkonflikt" (6x) "Laufzeitfehler" (23x), ""erreur d'exécution" (9x), "errore di runtime" (0x). Not very often. @KetZoomer I believe machine translation just ignores parts that cannot be translated and copies them verbatim. That would probably be okay, or where do you see problems? I just checked with an example of mixed language and code and it worked fine.

Comment: @Nick any reason to roll back to something that is not right? http://www.thepress.purdue.edu/sites/default/files/documents/ccsstyle.pdf and https://style.mla.org/cite-altered-quotation/ and https://writeanswers.royalroads.ca/faq/199102 and [Where does "emphasis mine" go in a quotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/90161) ... I can go on :D

Comment: @M-- Yep, because stylistically I didn't like it, also, the MLA is for scholars in literary fields, of which I'm not, so see no reason to abide by it, it also doesn't say use superscript text, which you changed as well, (I also note that all of your sources are American, I am not). Lastly, you removed "In English" from the title which is _the entire point of the question_. This is not a formal setting, and the question is my own, I'd prefer for it to be formatted the way that it is.

Comment: Removing *in English* was the courtesy of using MagicEditor, which was already added back before your roll back, so not relevant. MLA was part of one of the links I have provided, among others; so just referring to one to discredit the whole argument is not accurate. And I don't see this as a style which one would consider likable or not. In any case, I don't wanna make a fuss; it's your question, and that little change on MSO (we're not on SE-English) doesn't matter that much. Cheers.

Comment: @M-- That's no problem, just wanted to be clear, there was _some_ reasoning behind it, I appreciate the thought, but prefer it as it is, thanks (it also allows me to be explicit in the emphasis being _mine_, rather than people implicitly assuming it's mine from the fact it was known to be added)

Comment: @TylerH Sorry but regardless of where an error is thrown and whether it is crafted in code or not has no bearing on the fact that when it is thrown it is an output **not code**. Where it originates doesn't dictate whether it is code or not, it's simply an error message output, code can be the mechanism that throws it. I think it's an important distinction to make and why there is so much disconnect between what is and isn't code.

Comment: @Lankymart I think the error message is part of the code. Finding what part of the code threw the error is harder (if not impossible), if you do not know the error exact message. Figuring out what message is in the code when using a different language pack is probably not feasible if one doesn't even know why there is an error in the first place. 1/2

Comment: Translating the error will likely not produce the exact error message that a different language pack would throw. If I translate my error to the best of my ability and end up with "ListOverTheLineError", there's noway for anyone to find it looking through the JavaDoc or the Java SE source files of *any* language pack. 2/2

Comment: @Scratte What?? An error message is **not code**, don't know how to be any clearer. Locating where an error is thrown is not the error message itself and has no bearing on how to display the output of an error message.

Comment: @Lankymart It has a bearing if I want to locate it. Then I search for the message in the code itself, or in a properties files or table, and then I backtrack it. It's like isolating where a button or an input field in a user interface is. I start with the text. I find it to be very efficient.. An exception can be thrown with different messages. If I want to know where it's thrown with an exact message, it helps a lot to have the message.

Comment: @Scratte That's very convenient... if you control the entire codebase and all libraries used, good luck finding the source of an Automation Error in VBA like that

Comment: @Nick I do not need to control it, just have access. I'm not sure what you're arguing here. Should users not include error messages because there's a subset of frameworks that do not give developers access to view their code base?

Comment: @Scratte No, just that having an error message doesn't provide _any_ guarantee that you'll be able to find where the error occurred, VBA automation errors full error body can be as little as *"Automation Error - Unspecified Error"*, no stack trace, no line number, nothing, so referring to errors as code is unhelpful. It can definitely have _no_ bearing, even if you want to locate it.

Comment: @Lankymart I'm thinking of, specifically, things like `<asp:label>` that you use as an error message you display dynamically. It's output but it's 100% generated based on code/verbiage you wrote. Contrast this with a server/runtime error that you get that isn't something you intended/caused to show up. And even in those cases, you see a combination of prose and quoted code, e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNRoW.png

Comment: @TylerH Yes, but something like `<asp:label>` in an error message is never localised anyway, that is always `<asp:label>`? As for the screenshot, that is error messages "containing code". That to me isn't enough of argument to make for error messages are code.

Comment: What I usually do when I post non-English screenshots is that I post the screenshot as it is and translate the relevant parts in a paragraph below ([example](https://superuser.com/q/1325601/513819)). I guess that should probably apply to error messages too.

Comment: I'm done here, strong opinions without tolerance or willing to argue, deleted my answer and won't show up here again.

Comment: If you can't read/write just a little english you should not be a programmer/software developer. Just like english is chosen as the official international language that everyone should know and speak, the same goes for writing code. I don't know why .Net errors was translated in the first place. They never should have. In my language Danish the translations of Windows and error messages is so bad that not even Danish spekaing people understand them. The english is far more easy to understand.

Comment: I just got a banner on top of this question saying "Want to improve this post? Post an answer and..." Yes, I want to improve the question, no, I don't think posting an answer improves it and btw. I already posted one. And this question has such a high score it hardly needs improvement. What a strange banner.

Comment: @nivs1978 Fun fact. I learned how to program an Atari computer in Basic years before I learned English. I think I had a photocopy of a translated reference book and some example listings of simple programs. I was 6 or 7 years old. English terms like print were just literals to me. But that was then and now is now.

Answer (score 423, accepted):

Errors should be provided in full and as they appear on your screen. They should be provided in a text form as a citation (or in code block if the message is preformatted). You are quoting whatever software has given you this error. Do not change anything in the error message when adding it into your question. By translating you could change the meaning of the error message.

If you think that the error message will not be understandable you should add a translation *on top* of the original message or you can explain what the error message says in your own words.

Comment: I fully agree with this. It is often difficult to find the correct English translation of an error message in a foreign language, and translating it incorrectly makes the error unclear for _everybody_, including native speakers that would have understood the original error. For example Laufzeitfehler means runtime error, but Laufzeit can also be translated as 'operational time', 'execution duration', or even 'term' (as in 'duration', not as in 'concept'), which would be very confusing.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the responsibility of the OP to provide the translated error message instead of others having to interpret it? If they can't translate it then maybe [so] isn't the place for it.

Comment: I don't agree. We require minimal reproducible examples. If we can expect people to create these, we can certainly expect them to configure their setup so it provides error messages in English.

Comment: I don't think we should expect users to change their IDEs to suit us but if they are able to navigate [so] and ask a question they can most certainly translate an error message.

Comment: First paragraph perfect, second I disagree with. Non English error messages are not understandable by default (for an English-only speaker). A manual translation/explanation in English on top of the original message should be mandatory.

Comment: @Lankymart Isn't this the purpose of the error code?  Seems much more reliable than an amateur translation back into English.

Comment: @me "A manual translation/explanation to English ... should be mandatory." But only if possible. If for example there is this computer localized in Greek and I don't speak it, but it outputs an error message that's all Greek to me, I can only reproduce the error message "as is", hoping that maybe someone else might deliver a translation into English for me and others. These cases should also be ontopic here.

Comment: @Trilarion There is always going to be edge-cases, in the main though error messages should be in English. Although I'd question the point of posting such an error message on [so] in the first place as it sounds quite a niche topic and not likely to help others.

Comment: @Trilarion "These cases should also be ontopic here." Why? Because questions should be allowed to be unclear until someone else fixes them for you?

Comment: @Tom This was for the case where I don't speak the language. I guess, I could send the message once through google translate.

Comment: Translating the message yourself is obviously terrible (probably won't match the wording of the English message), but whenever possible programs should be run with `LANG=C` or `LC_ALL=C`, or equivalent option for non-Unix, to get the default  error messages (which are English by convention).  So in cases where it's easy, definitely do that.

Comment: @Roland If there's a minimal reproducible example, you can just run it yourself and get the English error message.

Comment: @Roland So you're saying we have to force people to install an English Windows, respectively the English language pack (which is several hundreds of MB large and there at least used to be licensing limitations for windows home installs) and configure their whole OS to use it before being allowed to post code that leads to .NET exceptions on SO? Particularly given that HResults are easy to interpret anyhow? I don't think so. There simply isn't one general solution for all languages and cases and a best effort approach can be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Roland Maybe you should rather ask Microsoft to report english error messages. my OS is in german, but every frigging software and tool I use can be configured to use english. Except .Net. It will always give me german error messages. I'm not happy about that, but I'm also not changing my complete OS to english. If that reduces my audience on SO, fine, thats my own problem. But enforcing english error messages when the tool gives me localized messages *against my own will* is unreasonable. If you have found a good solution for making MS tools spit out only english errors, I'm all yours...

Comment: @Polygnome so, you can't change the language using environment variables? I knew Windows was bad, but even developer bad?

Comment: @Braiam No, you can't. You are literally forced to re-install the OS with another language, as sometimes even installing the language pack isn't enough. Again, if you know a solution how to get the myriad of tools of MS that use the OS language (e.g. .Net, the console, PowerShell and whatnot) to use english instead, I'd be incredibly thankful as would probably thousands of other devs.

Comment: "If we can expect people to create these, we can certainly expect them to configure their setup so it provides error messages in English" - this is outrageous. Perhaps you have never actually gone through the effort required to switch between languages in some platforms.

Comment: @Voo Personally, I don't care at all about .NET. I care about languages I use. And I don't want people to be able to point to a canonical answer on meta that tells them they can post non-English error messages. If Microsoft makes sane configurations hard or impossible, we need an exception for that. I don't see why all tags should live with localized error messages because of this.

Comment: I fully support this. And please do not forget that even if everybody does his best to write correct English in SO site, many of us are not native English speakers. As far as I am concerned, I prefere read an original error message in French, Spanish, Italian or even German that a poor English translation.

Comment: @Roland My point is that the accepted meta post cannot simply be "only English language error messages accepted", because that's infeasible and unnecessary. The more subtle proposals like the one by Trilarion should work perfectly fine though.

Comment: @Voo It's been edited. It's less subtle now.

Comment: @Scratte Still seems perfectly reasonable to me: Provide the English text if possible with a reasonable amount of effort (true in many cases), if not provide the original and a best effort translation marked as such.

Comment: I don't understand the discussions about the edge-case of error messages in languages you don't speak. The most likely explanations would IMO be that the program is producing errors in the wrong language for some reason, and that should be on-topic, or that the poster is trouble-shooting for someone else and should then ask that third person for a translation. Can anyone describe any other realistic scenarios?

Comment: @HansOlsson your computer is configured for German but you can also speak English so you asked the question in English.

Comment: @user253751 but if my computer is configured for German I can likely understand German, and since I have to write my question in  English, I should be somewhat capable of translating it. 
That's not the edge-case being discussed. The edge-case is that the message is in German, but I cannot translate it.

Comment: Many errors are gobbledygook anyways, so an error message that is actually in a different language doesn't change my normal pattern: Google the exact text to learn more, then offer advice. I can just as easily search for Russian or German or Portuguese as I can for English. The most important thing is to have _the exact, complete error message_. Anything less, even in English, severely hampers my ability to answer the question. An attempt at translation is appreciated, but if the message is already unintelligible to the OP, then I can't expect them to translate accurately.

Comment: If you, as a reader, are frightened by an error message in a foreign language, then you can choose not to read any further and move to another question, just as you can for any obtuse error message that is difficult to decipher. But the post is still on-topic and, as long as the question and answers are in English, it is still useful information to have on SO. Even more so if we can close as a duplicate, because then SO will be able to capture those exact string searches and redirect to post with an English translation.

Comment: @Gabe And now try "Kellerspeicher" and get "basement" instead of "stack" which might slightly confuse things ;)

Comment: As somebody who worked with .NET for a while, I can confirm that the "localized" error message situation is quite hard to get out of in that family of languages, and on top of that, not all exceptions even have a HRESULT or useful error code, or anything to tell the exception apart from some other one, other than the exception type (which can be very vague, `InvalidOperationException` can mean just about anything). Unfortunately you are dependent on the message text sometimes.

Comment: Seems the we are not considering a very important point in my opinion. The search for an error message (when there are no error codes) is simply a lot more successful when you provide the error message in English than the same in other languages. But we cannot ask every poster to translate it with all the subtle nuisances that cannot be clearly seen by OP, we can simply search for the wrong term fooled by the OP translation. We are here to help so, copying the error in some, even imperfect, translators will give us (or at least to the more expert of us) enough info to solve the problem.

Comment: @Steve  by that same logic, someone searching for an answer is much better served by the original error message being shown here, than a translation, particularly if the translation is different to how the searcher would translate.

Comment: For me, I'd rather they keep it in the original language. For German in particular in my case, I've got a way better shot at understanding what the error is than if it's translated by somebody whose English might not be that strong. Some of these messages are hard enough to figure out in their original language! Going through a potentially questionalbe translation...?

Comment: I disagree with the last part of this, "If you think that the error message will not be understandable you can add a translation on top of the original message or you can explain what the error message says in your own words." This should instead be **must**. Someone posting an error message in Russian, Japanese, or another language with a completely different alphabet than English, really adds absolutely nothing to the post without an explanation or translation.

Comment: Spare a thought for those of us who support complex estates of legacy systems. The language of the error message is a pointer to the system that is producing the error. Our first stop is to search on the text of the error message to see what heppened last time someone saw the message. Please post the verbatim error message in searchable form.

Comment: @Dharman "Errors should be provided in full as they appear" - Why did you delete half of my exact error message then?

Comment: @RauliRajande I remove part of the title. I remove the insignificant part. It didn't change the meaning. If you want, you can still add the full error message in the body of the question. The title should describe the issue.

Answer (score 140):

As a potential FAQ item (rev2, see [previous revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/402224/1)):

**I got a non-English error message. It's not my own code that produced it.  How can I ask about it or include it in a question on Stack Overflow?**

If you can easily configure your software to produce English error messages, do so and provide them instead. In particular if someone points out a way to produce English error messages with reasonable effort, implement it and provide an English error message instead.

If you speak the language of the error message, provide the message "as is" (as text in the original language) and attach a personal translation of it into English. Include localization information about the used software.

Optional: If the language is one of the languages of the localized Stack Overflow sites (Portuguese, Russian, etc.) you could ask on one of them instead. Localized error messages may be reasonable search targets on localized Stack Overflow sites.

If you do not speak the language of the error message, provide the message "as is" and provide a machine translation, then mark it as such and mention that edits that provide a better translation are welcome. Include localization information about the used software.

---

Summary <sub>(inspired by [Voo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402216/are-error-messages-required-to-be-posted-in-english?cb=1#comment803500_402217))</sub>: When encountering non-English error messages try to change the language of the messages to English if possible with a reasonable amount of effort, if not provide the original and a best effort translation (including a possible machine translation) marked as such.

Comment: I slightly changed wording after sleeping once over it. The goal was to emphasize more that it's a last resort; trying to get English error messages was only strongly recommended before, it's required now. Also one is now required to at least deliver also a machine translation if one cannot translate on its own. That was not required before. I hope that's okay with previous voters.

Comment: How is that required now? The top Answer doesn't say it's required, but "you can add a translation", meaning it's optional.

Comment: @Scratte I require it now. In this answer it is required now. Top answer is a different answer, which requires less.

Comment: "*you could also try them*" - No, you shouldn't do that. Pick one site, don't cross-post. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/191410

Comment: There is a good chance that anyone familiar with the technology used will be able to fix up any problems in a machine translation. Can anyone attached a fixed-up machine translation?

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica Okay. Changed to "you could use them instead".

Comment: @user253751 Personally, I think automatic translations aren't all that bad. And they just keep getting better. Maybe in the future I should write in my mother tongue and use an automatic translation service instead of using my poor English.

Comment: This is really the better answer, IMO. Leave the original, but also include an English translation whenever possible. This has both the advantages of being able to look up the original error message text (where exact text is often very helpful) as well as making the meaning of the error message accessible to everyone on the site, not just those who speak the particular language in question. There's really no downside to following this answer's advice.

Comment: That's the most sensible approach by far. I' like to upvote this a thousand times, but alas, I got only one vote :-)

Answer (score 33):

In this particular case, the error message looks like it follows a standard pattern, so whether the line headings on the left are in English, German or whatever shouldn't matter too much to an SME used to these messages. Besides, there's the `800A000D` code, which is probably universal, regardless of the language of the IDE. Thus, for this particular case, I'd leave it with a comment

> Since Stack Overflow is an English site, posting English error messages will be more helpful to a large audience. If you can, please add a translation of the message.

However, if the *entire* error message is nothing but foreign language, potentially with a few line numbers or function names thrown in, I would go for the "Needs details or clarity" close option, as then the error is not understandable.

I don't think we can/should force people to install their IDEs in English, but should expect posts to be understandable for the audience on Stack Overflow. Fluent English isn't necessary, having your variable names to be correct English words neither. So as long as the error message is understandable, no action has to be taken; if the error message is not understandable and required to be able to understand the post, an attempt should be made at translating<sup>1</sup>.

---

If you happen to have your computer/IDE configured in English and the provided MCVE is correct, you can simply copy-paste the code, run it, and copy the resulting error message into the post itself, whilst retaining the original error message.

If it is rather easy to change the IDE language, such as in [Linux](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402286/5211833) or [R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13575180/5211833), suggest that the OP does that, since it would prevent any translation errors.

<sup>1</sup> I agree with [the answer by Dharman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402217/5211833) here, that the original message should be included due to the possibility of a translation error.

Comment: Why should we have to look up the error code?

Comment: @Lankymart if it's as common as a HTTP 403 error, there might be no need to look it up yourself. The OP, OTOH, can use it to search for what the common message associated with that error is in English and add that to the post.

Comment: @Adriaan if it's that common there is probably already a good canonical that answers the question.

Comment: Machine translations are often quite understandable. Should any random person be allowed to add one? Or does it have to be a translation by someone who's fluent in the language?

Comment: @user253751 if the rest of the post was originally in English (thus the OP demonstrated their skill) I think a machine translation verified by someone knowledgable in the programming language (who thus knows how such errors should look like) would be good. I'm hesitant with e.g. native Spanish speakers translating Spanish errors for code languages they don't know, since keywords are often very specific. An SME being fluent in the natural language of the error would of course be the best possible option.

Comment: @Adriaan I think errors are usually recognizable enough that you can tell if a keyword is wrong. E.g. if the translated error says "wrong kind: had int, expected string" someone experienced with the programming language should know that the english one says "invalid type: got int, expected string"

Comment: I agree with this answer specifically in this case. Often times we don't close individuals questions that are english as a second language, we work together to improve their quality. Would this be improved by adding a link to the relevant error code in the VBScript docs? Absolutely.

I would rather have the original context of the output of the code, on the off chance that there was something wrong with the localization of the code or errors, in order to further assist.

Answer (score 7):

I always try to give error messages in English and search for them in English such that I use `LC_ALL=C` or its equivalent when I'm debugging and asking others about an issue since, after all, I'm asking others to look at my problem and give me solutions, so I want them to not invest more effort than necessary.

Now that that's out of the way, should you make someone else's messages into English? Depends. If I can't find an answered question about the same message, I would replicate the issue and replace that message to make the question better. The answered question should be the best presented question about an issue, so having a error message in another language harms that presentation. If it's a duplicate... I really don't care about it.

Comment: I already saw a lot of half-baken softwares giving me error messages in Chinese, French, Russian, Czech, Japanese and languages which I have no idea what they are. Don't assume that there will be a magic flag easily reachable somewhere that will translate everything properly. Most of times there isn't any. And even if there is, I'm already very pissed off from errors featuring broken translations that sound as "all your base are belong to us" (Microsoft is a specialist in giving me that), so I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Those errors probably don't come from the compiler/interpreter/etc. but from the programmer itself. Those aren't on topic for SO anyways. Otherwise, do a list of software that is uniquely used in software development that doesn't include error messages in either english or some kind of error code.

Comment: The inner guts of SAP/ABAP is an example of a thing that is in scope of SO that might give some German error messages (just a very small niche, but it is nevertheless). BTW, there is a lot of specific frameworks and programming tools out there that might sometimes give errors that aren't in English. For example, a few years ago I had trouble with some legacy Java framework that gave me error messages in French, and I don't speak French nor was using anything that had something to do with French, so this happens sometimes.

Comment: @VictorStafusa again, this is about a general behavior. PHP, Python, Mono, Javascript, <insert languages with +0.5% usage in systems except MS's>, allow this

Comment: @Braiam To start, the error in the OP comes from the VBScript interpreter when run on a German Windows. PowerShell also spits out german error messages when run on german windows, as does `cmd.exe` (the older "shell" on Windows). Pretty much every MS tool spits out localized error messages. Even the *exceptions* that .Net Framework throws are localized on Windows. And there is nothing you can do about it except reinstalling the complete OS and switching the language, which many devs don't want to do for good reason (or even can't when working on a machine provided by the employer or customer).

Comment: @Polygnome **"except MS's"** Microsoft has demonstrated that it doesn't know what developers need. Those cannot be used as examples of common place behavior. If you exclude MS, the list would be about irrelevant software. Kneecapping every other language just because MS doesn't know how to create developer tools correctly isn't something we should create guidance around.

Comment: @Braiam You realize how widespread the tools used by MS are, right? You realize how prevalant Windows is, as an OS, right? You realize that a significant portion of developers work on Windows or with tools from MS, right? We *aren't* talking about some fringe or nichê tools, here. We are talking about a large amount of people who *are* affected by this nonsense from MS. being stubborn and sainyg "Thats an MS problem, not our problem" doesn't actually *solve* anything. The problem is still there for a large portion of devs.

Comment: @Polygnome again, **I do not care**. We can not make a exception just because MS being stupid. Every other language have sane behavior, whatever we decide should follow sane behaviors.

Comment: @Braiam Well, it is sad that you do not care about the problems your fellow developer face every day. And I'm glad that the most upvoted answer here is way more tolerant and interested in solving the problem, instead of stickling to principles. Yes, MS is being stupid, but punishing the average dev for MS behavior is just short-sighted, imho. We aren't here to play the blame-game, we are here to solve programming problems. At least we used to be.

Comment: @Polygnome I can't care because that's a problem MS created and you accepted when you bought yourself into the platform. Every other mayor language in the planet implemented this in a sane way. Allowing askers to do stuff based on a outlier doesn't do SO any favors. So, suck it up and complain to Microsoft, but don't make every other developer life more difficult!

Comment: @Braiam Playing the blame game doesn't solve any problem. And its not like developing on Windows or using some tooling from MS is a fringe case. According to statista, 60% of software dev in 2020 was on windows. I did not find any stats about the languages their OS are in, but I'm pretty confident it'll be a non-negligble share. And all of those have to deal with e.g. cmd.exe and PowerShell giving them non-english messages. Even if they'd prefer them otherwise. The top-voted answer offers a sensible approach to dealing with that, because instead of assigning blame, it solves the problem.

Comment: @Polygnome I don't play any game. **I do not want the exception to become the rule.** Whatever we decide, we shouldn't do it on the basis of exceptions.

Comment: @Braiam Well, it seems we fundamentally disagree. Fortunately, we don't need to. I can very much live with the two top-voted answers here, so I guess whats done is done.

Answer (score 7):

Like with everything else, if reading and understanding the error message is necessary to answer the question, the error message should be provided in English, or at least accompanied of an adequate translation.

If knowing the language of the posted error is required to have enough information to post an answer (and guesswork based on a couple of keywords interspersed with the rest of the natural language does not count), posting it in another language (without offering an alternative or adequate translation) **is the same as not posting it at all, similarly to posting error messages or code in images**.

Questions like that are liable to be closed as "needing clarity" or "needing debug details".

Answer (score 4):

By insisting on leaving the message untranslated, several things will happen:

- Alienate anyone not able to read the language
- Getting passed over by people not willing to spend time translating it

The post could be as well written as possible which is great and might take me a minute to read but forcing me to translate a small portion of it could easily double my time invested.

Why raise the barrier for people to read and answer the post? Is there an interest in German-speaking answers only?

It would take the OP a minute to translate the error and provide both versions but instead they are choosing to make several hundred people spend an extra minute to comprehend the post.

This attitude is literally anti-programming because they are okay with wasting 100 peoples' minute because they didn't want to use their own minute.

In the end it mainly hurts OP because a much more narrow audience is willing to fully read the question.

Comment: "It would take the OP a minute to translate the error". The faith that it's trivial translating error messages from any language into the canonical English error message is commendable, but very far from reality. A best effort translation is certainly helpful, but definitely keep the original if you can't provide the canonical translation.

Comment: @Voo really? I just put `LC_ALL=C` and all error messages become english.

Comment: @Braiam Clearly you haven't programmed in enough different environments and languages then.

Comment: @Voo If that's the case then OP would need to make peace with both of my bullet points and closing statement. I too recommended that OP has both versions in the question.

Comment: Re *"they are okay with wasting 100 peoples' minute because they didn't want to use their own minute"*: But this is the case for 99% of the users on Stack Overflow. Some even do it deliberately or can't be bothered to use the Shift key.

Comment: @Braiam `LC_ALL=C` only works on Linux/Unix. And only if the tool adheres to it. Microsoft has the extremely stupid and annoying tendency to post localized error messages, and I'm not changing my OS language because MS decides to screw people over. Every other tool properly uses english, except .Net and many other MS tools. If you have found a way to make MS tools give out english error messages without requiring me to change my whole OS, please, point it out...

Comment: @Polygnome shouldn't error messages be displayed to the user in the language they are most likely to understand, so probably in the language of the OS? I think this in one of the (yes sometimes annoying) things that the MS stack gets consistently right, in that sense they lead the way in how we should write our own apps, but who has time to put that level of effort in these days...

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Its exactly the wrong way to head down. I have good reason to want my error messages in english and my OS in german. These aren't error messages that the average end users sees, those are error messages tech savy users and developers see. Why MS think they know better than me in which language I'd want the error messages is beyond me. I have that problem with no other tool. literally one. Except thinks like .Net. And no, putting my OS into english can't seriously be the solution.

Comment: @Polygnome but isn't that in itself the wrong reason. Error messages _are_ for the average user, it is up to us as developers to try and write bug free software such that the user only sees error messages that they can process. Its only due to our shortcomings as developers that we force the users to manually report error messages through to "tech support", even then, my German speaking user surely would be speaking first to a German speaking tech support person? English isn't ubiquitous, not all developers speak or read english, why is it that every other platform outside of MS assumes we do?

Comment: @Chris Have you ever supported a global .NET application? In my experience getting exception messages in Chinese or Hungarian gets old very quickly and will quickly make you wish for English text. Also it's not as  if "Typenkonflikt: '[string:" was any more understandable to the average user than the English version. It's all greek to them anyhow, so why not make it easier on the developer? Note that Microsoft itself agrees that localizing exceptions was an error and has no plans on repeating this mistake with net core.

Comment: This will be my last comment on this, but my global apps use APIs to report exceptions and analytics back to me under the hood, I don't directly support end users, my regional based support team do that for me, because I can't answer calls from 200 million users. More importantly I make the software more sound than that, so I don't have that many users trying to report issues. When an exception does occur, the user sees a localised message that provides reassurance and a link and tracking number into our Support portal, that is also localised...

Comment: @ChrisSchaller The users of my software *never* get to see any system exception, they get sensible, localized error messages, of course. But we aren't talking about these kinds of error messages here. .Net literally localized the text of the exceptions. And many other tools MS tools that devs directly interact with, too. Those error messages aren't intended for the end user. You are comparing apples with oranges. The point is that MS takes the choice away. I can't even log exceptions in english (or ask about them on SO) while displaying a localized error to the user. MS uses the OS language.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller And since MS uses the OS language, I need to localize the errors anyways. Otherwise, I'd need a seperate server with the language pack of the target audience and couldn't ever support users with multiple languages on the same server. This just shows how much you compare things that have little to nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Chris Great so the user never sees the exception message - so it doesn't matter at all for them whether it is translated or not. But you collect stacktrace and exception information with your fancy APIs so *you* can actually debug the issue. At which point you now have to deal with a Chinese exception text. So given your approach there's also no advantage at all to translated exceptions.

Comment: @Voo I'm just surprised that this causes you such pain, in my apps all system exceptions are caught and wrapped with an ApplicationException that uses a resource string in the _actual_ exception, this is stored and logged in the developer language (German) but in all the interfaces (including the dev console) the UI uses i8nl concepts to translate and present that string to the user. It was a small amount of effort up front to ensure that long term our applications can be fully supported in multiple languages, .Net and Angular made this a no brainer... Thankyou Microsoft!

Comment: @Braiam I already saw a lot of half-baken softwares giving me error messages in Chinese, French, Russian, Czech, Japanese and languages which I have no idea what they are. Don't assume that there will be a magic flag easily reachable somewhere that will translate everything properly. Most of times there isn't any. And even if there is, I'm already very pissed off from errors featuring broken translations that sound as "all your base are belong to us" (Microsoft is a specialist in giving me that), so I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: @Chris Again, it's not about your exceptions, it's about system exceptions being localized. If I understand you correctly you're accessing undocumented internal fields of Exceptions to get to the resource string? Well I wouldn't call that good engineering (although there are workarounds to make this work), but much worse: it also doesn't work for all those exceptions that only store the translated text because a lower-level component already translated them (I can think of several examples there).

Comment: @VictorStafusa as I said [in another comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402216/are-error-messages-required-to-be-posted-in-english?cb=1#comment803695_402222), said software is unlikely to be exclusively in software development.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Again, you are looking at the wrong this. Everything you said is perfectly correct and the right way to head down. But as soon as you put your nice .Net application onto a server that doesn't use english, the error messages are non-english. Not the ones your users see, but the ones you as dev get to see because you log them somewhere. And then try to ask about the errors you see in your log on SO. Or you simply happen to develop your app on a non-english OS. Heck, even PowerShell spits out non-english error messages.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Its simply unreasonable to re-install the OS just to get PowerShell to spit out english messages. Again, if you happen to know a good way to make MS tools (PowerShell, CMD, .Net and whatever) spit out only english errors even when on non-english systems, please, please point it out how thats done. Again, its not about the messages we show our end users - its about the ones we as devs get to see.

Comment: "It would take the OP a minute to translate the error" - no. Simply no. Nothing could be further from the truth. Have you ever tried googling for the correct English translation of an error message in another language? There's a *lot* of guesswork / trial and error involved.

Answer (score 3):

My gut instinct is to say that any question containing non-English content **that is pertinent to the problem at hand** should be closed as "lacks detail", because there really isn't any good way to deal with this:

- Requiring askers to provide translations is just going to result in them posting Google Translated mumbo-jumbo, which helps nobody.
- Requiring askers to use an English OS, IDE, etc. is impractical.
- Allowing any sort of non-English content risks a slippery slope whereby such content becomes accepted, with the result that curation becomes more difficult.

For better or worse, English is the lingua franca of software development, and hence of any website that deals with software development. Being unable or unwilling to provide pertinent details in English is unfortunate, but ultimately not Stack Overflow's problem.

The other answers suggesting to use machine translations are both liable to change the question's meaning, and also place a burden on curators. If you ask a question here, it is **your responsibility to ensure it conforms with Stack Overflow's rules**, and one of those rules is that every question must be **detailed and specific**. The reason for this rule is that it makes your question accessible to more people, which both increases its chance of being answered and increases the chance that the question will be helpful to others. Non-English details make a question less accessible - hence they should be disallowed.

---

Update, prompted by comments from @Braiam and @user253751:

Questions lacking pertinent details in English detract from Stack Overflow's intent to be a high-quality knowledge base for as many people as possible. Consider:

- A question is asked for a specific problem.
- The question has pertinent details in a non-English language.
- The question is unique, i.e. has never been asked before.

Anyone with the same problem **will almost certainly not be able to find that question** because their pertinent details will almost certainly not be in the same non-English language. The likely result is thus that a duplicate question, completely in English, is asked for this same problem. Due to simple demographics and the aforementioned lingua franca, the English duplicate is far more likely to be answered.

The end result is that we now have two questions, **and we don't know that one of them is a duplicate**. Further, the non-English question is **almost certain to never be answered**, again due to demographics/lingua franca.

In essence, then, the original non-English question is dead weight. It is only discoverable by someone using that language, and even if it is found it has no answers. So it's not even neutral - it is patently **unhelpful** because it's a dead end. It would actually be far better if that question had never existed.

Comment: This is my stance, which is one reason I flagged the question to be closed in the first place. It wasn't until it was raised in chat against a comment I left, it all came to a head as we could not reach a consensus.

Comment: What if for example your company told you to go to China and make sure the company software runs on all computers there. Following this answer you would then not ask anything on StackOverflow about any Chinese error message that might pop up? Maybe that doesn't happen anyway, not sure.

Comment: "Requiring askers to use an English OS, IDE, etc. is impractical" eh really? I do this when I ask others for help with my problem. I don't want them misunderstanding nor having trouble parsing the message. It's my responsibility presenting the problem in the most clear and concise way possible. Failure to do so would only work to my own detriment.

Comment: @Braiam I agree, but at the end of the day that doesn't materially change my answer, so I omitted that line of reasoning.

Comment: @Trilarion Still the company's/my problem, not Stack Overflow's.

Comment: "Requiring askers to provide translations is just going to result in them posting Google Translated mumbo-jumbo, which helps nobody." - are  you sure? Half the time you can understand the error just with Google Translate and knowledge of the software that produced it.

Comment: Removed my answer as this sums it up succinctly enough.

Comment: @user253751 And the other half we can't, so then we fall back to having to use our judgement. Which leads to a different slippery slope of which questions with non-English error messages should be closed and which should be left open. The rule I am suggesting here is simple, clear, unambiguous, completely objective in its application, and will reduce the workload on curators.

Comment: @IanKemp I think you took my argument by the wrong side. It's the asker responsibility to present their problem in the best way possible. We, users, should require them to do so by the only reasoning that every question has to be of the highest possible quality.

Comment: @IamKemp If you can't understand the question, but you think someone else can, then don't answer it. Just like you would treat a question involving an unfamiliar technology. You could ask for clarification of some aspect that you think would help you to answer. Or, you could simply ignore the question.

Comment: @user253751 You are committing the fallacy of assuming that Stack Overflow exists to be a helpdesk for every unique problem that every programmer in the world may have - when in reality, Stack Overflow exists to provide solutions to problems that are **broadly applicable**.

Comment: @IanKemp ... and what makes the question not broadly applicable, compared to the same question with an English error message?

Comment: @user253751 that the error isn't in English.

Comment: @Braiam You mean to say all those French users are just a drop in the ocean? :D

Comment: Nice to see an answer that focuses on the long-term impact to the community, not just fixing the OP's problem.

Comment: @Braiam If the question starts with a localized error (because OP wasn’t able to get an English error message), there are two options I see: (1) The error is a common one that is already answered elsewhere; so the person that recognizes the localized error can vote as duplicate. (2) The error is something new that wasn’t answered before; the person answering is probably able to provide the English error message then, which can be edited into the question, making the question “broadly applicable”.

Comment: @poke again, I'm shooting myself in the foot failing to do so in the first place. It's on the best interest of the asker to provide the english version of the message anyways.

Comment: When I search for a specific issue, which I occasionally do, I often land on some post that has very little views, almost no votes. Some times there's an Answer on it. If I'm lucky, there are more than one, if there are none, I'll work it out and post one. You seem to argue such Questions are useless, I'd argue that they are not. They help making Stack the place to find an Answer to every question a programmer might have. If Stack only had the bigger Questions, they'd lose the diversity and special questions with narrow problems.

Answer (score 2):

Independently of what the decision about the canonical way of handling this will be, I suggest to encourage and teach people on how to run a program with an English locale, so that the error message will be English too. Not every program supports that, but I feel it would help in many situations.

On Linux for example the program should be run as this:

```
LANG=C your_program
```

Comment: This has been proposed in other (now deleted) answers and comments. This works for OSs/code languages where changing the locale is easy (such as Linux or R), but is neigh-on impossible and/or very costly for e.g. .NET, as you'd need to spend 80 quid and 200MB on installing a full English language pack for Windows.

Comment: The language pack for the IDE, and the locale for the system (which makes the error messages) is a different thing, obviously. Even if downloading a 200MB would be needed, that would be an option people should at least know about. I would just install it if that helps me.

Comment: PS: On Linux: `du -s /usr/share/locale` -->  `314M /usr/share/locale`

Answer (score 1):

The debugging close reason **explicitly requires** that users include any trace logs and error messages in their question:

> Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Since this site is English only, it should follow that the error message should be in English too.

> However there were arguments against it asking how errors are different to code and so should be allowed in non-English...

This argument makes no sense. We allow the code itself to contain non-English text because *the programming language itself is a language we understand*. If someone posts a question about changing the text color in a span tag, then it doesn't matter if their MRE contains this:

```html
<p>This text should be black <span>but this text should be blue</span>.</p>
```

this:

```html
<p>Este texto es negro <span>pero este texto debe ser azul</span>.</p>
```

or this:

```html
<p>Etot tekst chernyy, <span>no etot tekst dolzhen byt' sinim</span>.</p>
```

Because it's always a p tag and a span tag. It doesn't become a "razmakh" tag just because it's Russian. You don't need to understand non-code within the code to answer the question or understand the answer. The reason we make the exception for programming code doesn't apply to error codes.

Comment: // , Do Error Messages fall into the same category as "Output"?

Comment: @NathanBasanese What is the purpose of "// , "?

Comment: @NathanBasanese I think referring to both the result of running the program and error messages as output could get confusing depending on the context but I don't think it matters for this question. My point is that having the error message in a language other than English makes the question unanswerable and unanswerable questions should be closed.

Comment: Not many error messages are in anything that most ordinary people or even professionals would consider "English". The jargon and terms are often so terse and impenetrable that it requires some Googling to answer, and you can just as easily Google Russian as you can English. What would make the question unanswerable is if an attempt at translation failed in subtle ways... then I can't search in any language because the terms are all wrong. Definitely give me what the computer spat out and we can go from there.

Comment: The "jargon and terms" are still things that are known to people who use the programming language(s) in the question, even if you don't personally consider them English. If your argument is that programming languages are as far from English as Russian and Google Translate is good enough then I don't understand why we're an English only site in the first place.

Comment: @BSMP Whew. Yeah. Agreed. It's a good thing that's not my argument.

Answer (score 1):

My belief is that you would change the error to english, or at least provide some sort of translation. Make sure that it can be presented to the audience. It doesn't have to be in english, but if you are asking an english audience, make sure they can read it. Saves time with translating and then figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you use software that language is switched to X, then search for information and ask for support at sites which language is X.

If a program says you *"ошибка: невозможно прочитать файл"*, why do you ask for help at Stack Overflow which is English-speaking site? If you do this, there are problems:

- People who will search for the same error message but in English won't find your question at Stack Overflow.
- People who will search the error message in your language probably don't understand English, and so Stack Overflow answers won't be useful for them.

Thus, such answers would be useful only for narrow audience who speaks both English and your language.

The only reasonable case when you use a program in non-English language and ask for help in English is when there is no translation of this program to English.

There are also cases when you can't change language. But if you can, please change and try to get error in English. You will probaby even find a solution without asking a new question at Stack Overflow, if you search the error message in English.

Comment: Those are mighty big assumptions! If I run a program that gives me an error message in a different language than English, you're assuming that 1. I speak that language and that 2. I do not speak English. I'm not entirely sure why you'd make such assumptions.

Comment: @Scratte, if you use a progam in a language you don't understand, it means that you need this program very much and there is no translation to English / to your language (I updated the answer). It's very rare case. If you use a program in your native language, why do you ask for help in English?

Comment: What if it's not your native language? I know someone working as Brit for a British company which supports server parks. Also abroad, and one of their clients has configured their servers in French. They don't speak a word French, but can still write perfectly valid C++ for that server. The problem comes when there are errors, which will be thrown in French. Same holds for e.g. expats moving to another country where the sysadmin has installed all PCs in the local language, which they might not speak.

Comment: @Adriaan *"I know someone working as Brit for a British company which supports server parks. Also abroad, and one of their clients has configured their servers in French."* - o/ I'm one of those people (except it's not server parks, but smaller groups of servers)

Comment: That is very simply because I am using a library/OS that gives error messages not in English. It is not that uncommon and there is no Stack Overflow in Swedish or in French. I think you may need to revise "It's very rare case.". I know of a project that started in one country with every single variable and error message in the local language and later outsourced to a different country. The error codes are fortunately searchable :)

Comment: I might speak perfect English, and be able to write a question in perfect English, but happen to program on the family computer, which is configured in Finnish (or any other small language). Resources in that language are going to be very scare, so looking for them is rather a waste of time. Especially given that I speak English, why would you force me to reconfigure that computer, even though everything else in my question is in perfect English, including my own translation/summary of the error message?

Comment: Bottom line: a lot of people have their systems configured in a language other than English, for a plethora of reasons. Telling them to go somewhere else, even though they speak perfect English and can write good and on-topic questions is much too harsh in my opinion.

Comment: @Adriaan How about if I help out on your family computer? I speak English, but do not speak Finnish. Trying to write a post in Finnish (if there was such a site) would be a complete disaster :)

Comment: @Scratte,I still think this is a rare case. If you need support servers/clients in language you don't understand, there are much more problems.

Comment: @Adriaan _"why would you force me to reconfigure that computer"_. Because your question will be much better if the error message will be in English. For those who will answer you question, and for those who will search for the same problem. You ask for help, but don't want to spend time to reconfigure the computer. Why does someone have to spend time to answer your question then?

Comment: @Scratte, your family uses Finnish as their first language, and you do not even speak this language?

Comment: @anton_rh I do not think so. There are plenty of developers working on OS/Server not in their own languages and not in English. Try to work a year in France. I expect a lot of other users may face a similar issue having a common error code or even the same non-English error message. It seems to be that you have been fortunate to not have these issues, but limiting the usefulness for others due to that doesn't seem reasonable to me. (My scenario was working on a computer that belongs to Adriaan's family, or a Finnish company or a French company.. a system where I'm *not* to change the language)

Comment: Even working as a Frenchman in a French company, if the sysadmin does not allow you to change the system language. It's too harsh to block you from asking here, especially if you speak perfect English and your entire question is on-topic. And, as mentioned by others in this thread, reconfiguring e.g. Windows (for .NET errors) costs 80 quid to buy a new language package. Forcing me to ask help in the system language is a needless restriction if I otherwise speak and write proper English.

Comment: @Scratte, such answers would be useful only for English-speaking developers working in France (I don't think there are much of them). I still think, that you have to reconfigure computer and get error message in English. It may be helpful even for you. You can search for that error message in English and you will probably get a solution without asking at SO.

Comment: @Adriaan _"It's too harsh to block you from asking here"_. I think it is fine. I would never ask a question at SO with error message in my native language.

Comment: @anton_rh Maybe not. But there are a lot of French speaking people with French systems. They may not be able to change the system settings, and they may all be using Stack Overflow. So now you have lots of users that would find those posts useful. Your argument that it's only very rare is a bit questionable.

Comment: @Scratte, _"you have lots of users that would find those posts useful"_ and all of them are French-speaking.

Comment: Speaking one language does not exclude being able to speak another, @anton_rh. And translating messages does not in any way ensure that the message corresponds to the English equivalent. As had been mentioned it's not feasible to install a different language pack on a number of scenarios.

Comment: @Scratte, the audience is still narrow. I think there are less than 10% French-speaking people on Stack Overflow. Even if there are more, we do not speak about French specifically (which I think is quite popular). There are other languages. The error message can be in some "small" language and there can be less than 1% people on Stack Overflow who can understand it. If you can't change language, then ok. But if you can, you MUST change the language of the program and provide the English version of the error message in your question.

Comment: Changing language to English may be better even for you. My native language is Russian, but I use programs mostly in English. Because there are much more information in English than in Russian. I can get some text from UI or error message and search for it in Internet and find a lot of information. And I think, if you use program in your language, but search for info in English or ask a question on SO (which is also English), you have the same problem.

Answer (score -11):

This shouldn't be a strict requirement as translation is not really needed in most cases.

Answer (score -17):

In my opinion, an error message should always be in the language the programmers work with. Not only the error messages **but also the comments and inline code documentation** should be written in the same language.

If I have only German speaking developers and users in a company, I think that the error messages can also be made in German.

If there is a main company language, then this should be used. If there are many languages within a company, English is often used, because usually almost every developer understands English.

Comment: That would *severely* minimize the number of people able to help. In the past I've even asked to translate variable names into English, just to be able to make easier sense of code. (No I am not a native English speaker – but when programming, I am.)

Comment: Very much agree that the program should be in the common language of the people that work with it – *which is English the moment you exposes it to the internet*. As soon as code *might* end up on SO or another international context, it is *not* just "developers and users in a company" anymore.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I agree with you, when you expose it to the internet, but if your software is only running on intranet and - in order not to sound degrading- the caretaker also uses the software, then you should use the language of your company.

Comment: @Marco Once you post part of the code on [SO], or otherwise expect people on the internet to help, then it is *not* just on the intranet. Also, any error that is relevant *both* for "the caretaker" *and* [SO] is a design issue much larger than what [SO] can help with...

Comment: What is your proposed solution *for Stack Overflow*. So within a company, sure, do whatever the boss tells you to do. But here on Stack Overflow, and for this question specifically, what do you propose that SO does with non-English error messages, given that we require at least the surrounding text in the post to be English? This post, as it currently stands, has barely any relation to the question posed.